# Xcode 4 autocompletes "vector" to "std::__1::vector" when "using std::vector;"

Tags: c++, xcode4, autocomplete

Whenever I have `using std::vector;` in my translation unit, Xcode autocompletes `vector` to `std::__1::vector`. The same is true for all the other classes I've tried from the `std` namespace.

This is very irritating, as I've been in the habbit of typing `vec` and then hitting <kbd>return</kbd> for `vector`, or `str` <kbd>return</kbd> for `string`, but instead I have to <kbd>delete</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> every time because Xcode writes out `std::__1::vector<class _Tp>` or `std::__1::string` instead.

What's going on here?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.2 on OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: In libc++ `std::__1::vector` is the real name of the template. libc++ uses inline namespaces to do versioning and provide some protection against accidentally linking ABI incompatible implementations together. The inline namespace it uses is `__1`. I'm not sure why autocomplete is acting that way for you, as I'm not seeing the same thing.

Comment: Please file a bug report...

Comment: @MarcGlisse How do I do that?